# .htaccess - issue with folder once I get rid of the extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, trailing-slash

So I have managed to get rid of the php extensions through the .htaccess handler, but the problem occurs with one particular url which shares the name with a directory.

Ie. the directory, which is in the root, is called "somename" and the page is called "somename.php",
the path looks like this: www.domainame.com/somename/ for the directory, and this directory contains the following files: page1.php; page2.php etc. so the url to page1.php is www.domainame.com/somename/page1.php.

Now, the link on the menu for the page that features the urls for page1.php; page2.php; page3.php etc. is somename.php. But none of the links for page1.php; page2.php etc. are featured on the menu dropdown, instead you have to click on the "somename.php" on the menu bar and once a visitor is on the "somename.php" page they can click on a particular thumbnail to get to the page1.php, page2.php etc..

The problem occurs once I get rid of the php extension through .htaccess and when I click on the somename(ie.somename.php) on the menu bar I end up in the "somename"(www.domainame.com/somename/) directory instead of on the somename.php.

I have tried removing trailing slash at the end but the same issue persists. Ie.once I click on somename.php- it should take me to www.domainame.com/somename page but it takes me to the actual directory www.domainame.com/somename/
I have tired many different solutions bu I can't get this to work.
Please help!
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea here that should works actually the .htaccess file takes the both name if the directory is available with same name it will redirect to that directory so, here you can put index page on that "somename" directory and in this file you right the code to redirect to this page.

Comment: Good idea. I shall try it out. Thank you! My only concern is that it will redirect to directory again(??)